# How to fix "Incorrect date value: '2020' for column 'StartDate' at row 1" when trying to insert date into database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I'm trying to insert data from a form which are, an id, 2 dates, a string, and a decimal. but it gives the error above.

columns are: ID:int, startdate:Date, enddate:Date, number:int, string, Decimal.

I have already tried adding all those `date()` functions and `strtodate()` and stuff like that, but nothing worked.

```php
if (isset($_POST['submitReservation'])) {
    $startDate = $_POST['startDate'];
    $endDate = $_POST['endDate'];

    $linens = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['linens']);
    $peopleAmount = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['persons']);
    $number = 50;
    $userID = $_SESSION["UserID"];

    $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO reservation (TenantId, StartDate, EndDate, Number_Of_Persons, Linens, Cost) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $sql->bind_param("iiiisd", $userID, $startDate, $endDate, $peopleAmount, $linens, $number);
    $sql->execute() or die(mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Comment: You must remove `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: @Dharman just using it to see what's going wrong

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Which value do you try to insert into that `StartDate` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are casting the dates to int  `$sql->bind_param("iiiisd"`

Edit: MySQL expects a string, so try `$sql->bind_param("issisd"`

Comment: hmm, so what should I use, cuz I can only use: string, int, double, blob

Comment: use string, that´s what MySQL is expecting

Comment: I dont know why your answer got downvoted because it worked

Answer (score -2):

If you are using the standard PDO library you can use bindParam() or bindValue() and specify the type e.g.

```
if (isset($_POST['submitReservation'])) {
    $startDate = $_POST['startDate'];
    $endDate = $_POST['endDate'];

    $linens = $_POST['linens']);
    $peopleAmount = $_POST['persons']);
    $number = 50;
    $userID = $_SESSION["UserID"];

    $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO reservation (TenantId, StartDate, EndDate, Number_Of_Persons, Linens, Cost) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $sql->bindParam(1, $userID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindParam(2, $startDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindParam(3, $endDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindParam(4, $peopleAmount, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->bindParam(5, $linens, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindParam(6, $number, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->execute();
}
```

Comment: I see you are using mysqli, you should probably change this to use PDO instead but if you have to use it for some reason then musashii is correct it needs to be cast as string